# Как GPU.js, asm.js и другие библиотеки получают доступ к ресурсам?

Tags: javascript, gpu

Существуют библиотеки на JavaScript, позволяющие задействовать ресурсы устройства более эффективным образом - например, [GPU.js](https://gpu.rocks) использует в расчётах видеокарту, [asm.js](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asm.js) применяет компиляцию под конкретную платформу. Но как можно использовать видеокарту для расчётов, минуя библиотеку, и можно ли?

Речь о доступе к ресурсам системы из браузерного JS.

Answer (score 1):

Всё оказалось весьма прозаично, надо было просто заглянуть в документацию. Как всегда :)

GPU.js, судя по всему, работает через компиляцию шейдеров внутри WebGL - это можно понять, прошерстив [README библиотеки на GitHub](https://github.com/gpujs/gpu.js).

asm.js является подмножеством JavaScript, код для которого обычно генерируется с помощью [Emscripten](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emscripten), так что тут тоже ничего удивительного.